# How to add filter into rights module of yii?

Tags: yii

I want to add filter into the cgridview of rights module of yii.

this is the cgridview of rights module

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}",
        'emptyText'=>Rights::t('core', 'No users found.'),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'grid-view assignment-table'),
        //'filter'=>$dataProvider,
        'columns'=>array(
            array(
                'name'=>'name',
                'header'=>Rights::t('core', 'Name'),
                'type'=>'raw',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'name-column'),
                'value'=>'$data->getAssignmentNameLink()',
                'filter'=>'name',
            ),
            array(
                'name'=>'assignments',
                'header'=>Rights::t('core', 'Roles'),
                'type'=>'raw',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'role-column'),
                'value'=>'$data->getAssignmentsText(CAuthItem::TYPE_ROLE)',
            ),
            /*
            array(
                'name'=>'assignments',
                'header'=>Rights::t('core', 'Tasks'),
                'type'=>'raw',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'task-column'),
                'value'=>'$data->getAssignmentsText(CAuthItem::TYPE_TASK)',
            ),
            array(
                'name'=>'assignments',
                'header'=>Rights::t('core', 'Operations'),
                'type'=>'raw',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'operation-column'),
                'value'=>'$data->getAssignmentsText(CAuthItem::TYPE_OPERATION)',
            ),
            */
        )
    )); ?>
```

This is the actionview of assignmentcontroller

```
public function actionView()
    {
        // Create a data provider for listing the users
        $dataProvider = new RAssignmentDataProvider(array(
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>50,
            ),
        ));

        // Render the view
        $this->render('view', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }
```

How can I add filter into cgridview of rights module?

Answer (score 0):

if i get your question exactly you are trying to use the filter inside CGridView and it's not working.
if this is your question then the answer is :

in your action

```
public function actionView()
{
  $model=new RAssignmentDataProvider('search');
  $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['RAssignmentDataProvider']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['RAssignmentDataProvider'];

    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

in your View

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
     ...


 ?>
```

In this way when you use the filter it's call the search function and update the CGridView with the filtered values

Note : if you look at the admin action and the admin view that generated by Gii you will find the same code above.

Comment: I got the error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" at $model=new RAssignmentDataProvider('search'); full error http://i993.photobucket.com/albums/af56/thar5oe/PHPwarning_zps746229b6.png